# MVC 3 Validation: How can I validate matched input elements without using a form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

Am using MVC 3 on a new project and on the learning curve.

Situation: I have input tags (using unobtrusive validation) in a `<tr>` and I would like to independently submit the values for each `<tr>` via `$.ajax`, but only after they are valid. I take care of what/how I read from the inputs to transmit to the server.

Options: Put each form in a `<tr>` and validate form?? #multiple `<td>` elements **OR** Change my layout from tables?? #really

Question: Is there a way to validate a bunch of inputs e.g. `$("#tr1 input").validate()`?

Help.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a form?  The entire validation system is built around forms, as is HTML.  Even if using ajax, you should still use a form.

Comment: I'd need a form for each `<tr>` but it has multiple `<td>`s. `<tr><form>`?? Other tags create layout issues.

Comment: No, you don't have a form for each tr.  That's not legal HTML anyways.  You have one form for the table, but you use any of an umber of methods to tell the post method which record you are dealing with (usually an id set in a current record hidden or similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to ditch MVC validation and handle my own validation (FREEDOM! a cross between COLD TOLD and Michael Franc's valuable input) with help from the validity library: http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/ I love the flexibility with this and doesn't require the use of forms, just employ some common convention in your application e.g `class="required"` and create a reusable function with lines like: `$(".required").require();`. Works beautifully with both forms or ajax.

Thanks for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

why not write your own validation in some sort of validating the element before running ajax could be something like this

```
 var value=$("#tr1 input").val() /// this might cahnge depending on what value you are sending 
    var validator=false;
    if(value!="")
    {
    validator=true;

    }

    if(validator)
    {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/test.html',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
      }
    })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I want to make use of the validation that comes with `@Html.EditorFor` which reads attributes from the model, else MVC dwindles in significance.

Answer (score 0):

Unobtrusive validation in Asp.Net Mvc is using internally jquery validation plugin. When html is created metadata attributes are added to your elements and, I think that you can use them and do something like this:

```
$("#myform").validate().element("selector" );
```

From http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. So you are suggesting a global form I guess. Am thinking: `$("#tr1 input").each(function(){$("#form").validate().element($this)});` until I hit an error. Will it display the message next to the label e.g. "Name Required"?

Comment: One form on page and then... $("form").validate().element("#tr1 input");